# Is there a function (or a better way to) aggregate count the number of values using two columns with similar values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

As shown in the image,

- Two of the columns have the same kind of data.
- **Type1** is the primary type for a Pokemon and **type2** is the secondary type for a Pokemon.
- The same type like *grass*, *ground*, *poison* can appear in type1
  column as well as typ2 column
- For example for the first row *ground* is *type1* but for second and
  third row *ground* is *type2*

Now, what I am trying to do is get all the pokemon with same type *irrespective of type1 or type2*, for example, here count of ground would be 5 and poison would be 4 and so on(even if 4 ground appears in type2 and 1 in type one)

[image: dataset]

```
type2_count = {}
type_count = {}
for i in type1:
    type_count[i]=type_count.get(i,0)+1
for i in type2:
    type_count[i]=type_count.get(i,0)+1
print(type_count)
```

I am expecting the count for each type of pokemon (irrespective of type1 or type 2)

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe, we need it to help you. Don't post images

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use

```
# with numpy
type_counts = np.hstack(df[['type1', 'type2']].values)
type_counts  = dict(zip(*np.unique(type_counts , return_counts=True)))
print(type_counts)

# using pandas
print(df['type1'].append(df['type2']).value_counts().to_dict())

{'ground': 5, 'poison': 5, ....}
```

Comment: @NirdeshDwa If it was helpful do accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
pd.Series(df.type1.to_list() + df.type2.to_list()).value_counts()
```